# Is it possible to link two VPS Cloud servers together?

Tags: ipv4

Is it possible to link two VPS Cloud Servers together to be used as one. If I have two vps cloud servers and each have 80GB of space and 1TB bandwidth can they be linked together as one to have 160GB of space and 2TB of bandwidth?

Comment: Depends on the service provider and a number of other factors that are not provided.